# Prevent the access from copying a file when other resources are using it

Tags: windows, file-locking

In my application, i have one exe file that will do some conversion on my videofiles in a directory, and also i have used cute ftp to transfer the files present in the directory to another server.

CUTE FTP is configured to be run on every mins.

When 25% of job is over for a video file, CUTEFTP is transferred that file to other server.

What are the ways to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process the file in a different directory and then **move** it to a place where CUTE FTP will pick it up after the conversion is finished.

[EDIT] Don't use `copy`, use `move`. Both directories must be on the same harddisk. When using the Windows Explorer, use "Cut" or just drag the file with the mouse. Make sure there is no little "[+]" when you drop it.

Comment: If its a 2GB file, anyway it takes some time to copy and paste file.

Again the same problem will occur

Comment: Don't copy but **move** the file. Make sure both directories are on the same harddisk; then the move will take the same time, no matter how big the file is.

Comment: Does it solve CUTEFTP file transfer problem as discussed above?

Comment: It should since CUTEFTP can't see the file while it's being converted.